# jQuery closest div with specific class/id

Tags: jquery, html, replace, closest

I need your help.
This code works fine for me:

```
<div class="grauereihe">
    <div class="kleinesbild">
        <a data-lightbox="ags1" class="bildtopa" href="images/image1.jpg">
            <img class="bildtop" src="images/produkte/KHF/KHF-DN40-03-2.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="infozeile">
        <div class="produkttext">
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image2.jpg" />
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>


<script>
$('.produkttext img').on({
    'mouseover': function() {
        var images = $(this).attr('src');
        $('.bildtop').attr('src', images);
        $('.bildtopa').attr('href', images);
    }
});
</script>
```

but i need this code for more than one .grauereihe, like:

```
<div class="grauereihe">
    <div class="kleinesbild">
        <a data-lightbox="lb1" class="bildtopa" href="images/image1.jpg">
            <img class="bildtop" src="images/image1.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="infozeile">
        <div class="produkttext">
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image2.jpg" />
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="grauereihe2">
    <div class="kleinesbild">
        <a data-lightbox="lb1" class="bildtopa" href="images/image1.jpg">
            <img class="bildtop" src="images/image1.jpg" />
        </a>
    </div>
    <div class="infozeile">
        <div class="produkttext">
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image2.jpg" />
            <img class="kleinegalerie" src="images/image3.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So i thought of replace the `src` and `href` with closest-function (or parent), but I can't get it work. Like:

```
<script>
$('.produkttext img').on({
    'mouseover': function() {
        var images = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).closest('img').find('.bildtop').attr('src', images);
        $(this).closest('a').find('.bildtopa').attr('href', images);
    }
});
</script>
```

Can anyone help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get the first ancestor, you can use [`closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) method. As the `closest()` method gives you the closest ancestor and the element you're looking for is not an ancestor, you can traverse to the closest parent element and then use [`find()`](https://api.jquery.com/find/) method to get the descendant element.

```
$('.produkttext img').on({
    'mouseover': function(){
        var images = $(this).attr('src');
        $(this).closest('.grauereihe').find('img.bildtop').attr('src', images);
        $(this).closest('.grauereihe').find('a.bildtopa').attr('href', images);
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try below

one more thing I can see you have put class grauereihe2 please convert it to also grauereihe
And put your code in document ready is a good practice.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(e) {
  $('.produkttext img').on({
    'mouseover': function(){
        var images = $(this).attr('src');
        var parent = $(this).closest('.grauereihe')
        parent.find('.bildtop').attr('src',images);
        parent.find('.bildtopa').attr('href',images);
    }
  });
});
</script>
```

Comment: yes sir! thanks a lot. i replaced closesst with closest and it works perfect!